Deleted recent question
Till yesterday there was a question on "Alternative of SD and variance for non-normal variables". I was following the interesting answers, but suddenly I find that "This question was voluntarily removed by its author". Can anyone post what was the entire question? the page link - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/648190/alternatives-of-sd-and-variance-for-non-normal-variable
I feel questions should not be deleted so quickly.

I undeleted the question

@kjetil-b-halvorsen Lots of thanks! for your so quick action!

As often on SE, such rules are based on thought and experience about the interests of the OP and of the community. A grey area I've often seen, and experienced personally,  is that a good answer not yet upvoted allows an OP to delete their thread. Reasons might be one or more of (a) failure to understand the goals of CV (b) embarrassment about what turned out to be an obvious question (c) eliminating evidence that might be helpful to the competition (those people wishing to steal OP's ideas) (d) covering up when the question was an assignment in disguise (e) whatever else.

The thread, however, is likely to disappear again. For the record, there were several comments, but no answers (as implied by the answer here of @Sextus Empiricus).


I feel questions should not be deleted so quickly.

The question was closed and there seems no indication that the poster wants to edit or improve the question. Without the close reason being resolved and no intention by the original poster to make edits, there should be few problems with the original poster deleting the question. This is up to them and not the community.
No answers were harmed by the deletion of the question. If there are answers (or I believe it needs to be upvoted answers), then it is not possible to remove a question.

A key fact that belongs here is that the OP themselves deleted the question.
